# How can I apply a global pedestal to PulseAudio?

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, volume-control

On my system, analog output works, but the volume of the headphone output is very low. Internal speakers work well, and the volume level is reasonable. However, even at 150%, the volume of headphone output is barely audible (`alsamixer` command line utility also at full volume).

Is there a way to set a constant boost or pedestal to the headphone output? What I mean is, applying a strengthening effect to the baseline to which the sound levels in the volume mixer are compared.

There seem to be [some](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux-source-2.6.22/+bug/125332) [reports](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/pulseaudio/+bug/544357) [relating](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/271519) to this on Launchpad - does anyone know of a workaround or solution?

Edit: I forgot to mention that sometimes, when the speakers are enabled (the output is set to "Analog Output"), there is also sound from the headphone output - in these cases, the volume level is a-ok in the headphones as well. However, having the speakers on all the time can be a nuisance.

Answer (score 1):

In older laptops there used to be a switch to toggle the front output between line-out and headphone modes. Maybe this is what you are experiencing.

Even if this is not the case, since the dumbed down interface of the sound menu does not show all the available switches, try to install gnome-alsamixer and crank both master and any headphone you encounter to full and try all the checkboxes.

Comment: There is no hardware switch on my laptop. 'gnome-alsamixer' did bring out some new functionality, so thanks for the hint - however, the problem persists.